# How can I represent an "infinite" set based off a predicate, without storing all the elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For homework, I was asked to write a class that acts like a mathematical - i.e., potentially infinite - set. The constructor needs to have a parameter that will be given a function that returns a boolean value (a boolean *predicate*). It will be given as a `lambda`, for example `lambda x: x%3==2` or `lambda x: x*x>5`.

The resulting object should represent the set of all natural numbers(including 0) that satisfy the predicate.

I also need to implement `__or__`, `__and__` and `__sub__` to give the union, intersection and difference of two sets.

So far, I have this code:

```
class Infset:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.inf = set()
        self.x = 0
        while True:
            if f(self.x) == True:
                self.inf.add(self.x)
                self.x += 1
            else:
                self.x += 1
```

Of course, this really does try to make an infinite set, which results in a `MemoryError`.

How can I represent a potentially infinite set with finite storage space?

Comment: Maybe make it a generator?

Comment: Using a Python set doesn't make sense here (as you may have realized). Instead store the boolean function in your objects (it really fully describes the set). For the operators you can create new boolean functions by joining the existing ones with appropriate logical operations.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments! I think I got it!

Comment: I removed the "update" from the question, as it asks something separate. It appears the corresponding question was also posted separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870268).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing numbers, you need to store the function `f` itself. To do unions and so on, you need to create a new `f` based on `self.f` and `other.f` which gives the right answer for whether a given `x` is in the union.

Comment: Ohhh!! so I don't have to store all the numbers but instead thing of Infset as like a mold for the numbers? and instead of touching the numbers modify the molds to fit the union and other methods? so that when I place numbers x it will return the values I want?

Comment: Sounds like you've got the idea.

Comment: Thank you! I got to conceptualize it better! hehehe

Comment: Hey I just encoutered another problem. I can't seem to make the "or" work in the __or__ method. same goes for the __and__ as well. it just checks the first condition and ignores the second. What can I do about this?

Comment: You didn't create a new function; `self.f or other.f` is just equivalent to `self.f`. But also please don't edit your question after it has been answered; if you have another question, post it as a new question.