# How to combine two boolean lambda functions to make a new boolean lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, higher-order-functions

Given two lambda functions like

```
A = (lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
B = (lambda x: x % 2 == 1)
```

How can I create a new function, that returns `True` for each `x` where either `A(x)` or `B(x)` (or both) returns `True`?

I tried:

```
C = (A | B)
D = A or B
```

neither of these works.

I can hard-code equivalent logic like:

```
E = lambda x: x % 2 == 0 or x % 2 == 1
```

which gives the right result; but how can I take the existing `A` and `B` and use them to create the new function programmatically?

Comment: If your `f` are uncalled functions, they are always evaluated as `True` in conditions. That means `self.f or other.f` → `other.f`.

Comment: How can I make a function that takes in the two function's limitations?

Answer (score 2):

Use another layer of `lambda` wrapping, like so:

```
A = lambda x: x%2==0
B = lambda x: x%2==1

C = lambda x: A(x) or B(x)
```

Testing it:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(f'A({i})={A(i)!s:5} B({i})={B(i)!s:5} C({i})={C(i)!s:5}')
... 
A(0)=True  B(0)=False C(0)=True 
A(1)=False B(1)=True  C(1)=True 
A(2)=True  B(2)=False C(2)=True 
A(3)=False B(3)=True  C(3)=True 
A(4)=True  B(4)=False C(4)=True 
A(5)=False B(5)=True  C(5)=True 
A(6)=True  B(6)=False C(6)=True 
A(7)=False B(7)=True  C(7)=True 
A(8)=True  B(8)=False C(8)=True 
A(9)=False B(9)=True  C(9)=True
```